# Possible bug on R with chron and sapply

Tags: r, sapply, chron

I have a problem with R, a chron object and sapply function. I changed the default origin:

```
chron_start <- chron("01/01/2010", "00:30:00",origin.=c(month=1, day=1, year=1900))
ch <- chron_start+(0:(365*24-1))/24
```

Now, if I run:

```
> sprintf("%s", years(ch[1]))
[1] "2010"
```

But, If I run it iteratively with sapply I get:

```
> anios <- sapply(ch, function(x){sprintf("%s", years(x))})
> anios[1]
[1] "2080"
```

So it gets 70 years ahead, which is the difference between my origin (1900) and the defaults origin (1970).

I'd like to ask if this happens to you to, in order to send a bug report, or if there is an explanation to this behaviour and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance!!

P.S.: my R version is "R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)", running on GNU/Linux openSUSE Leap 42.2 64 bits. Chron package version is 2.3-45

Comment: I get this behavior on R 3.4.1 on windows 7 with Chron 2.3-50.

Comment: `sapply` (like `lapply`) is supposed to act on `list` objects. If they are not, a call to `as.list` is performed. See that `as.list(ch)` will lose any indication on the origin. So `years` will assume the standard POSIX origin (January 1st, 1970). Also, in your example you can simply try `sprintf("%s",years(ch))`

Comment: Actually what I am doing is a bit complex than that, so `sprintf("%s", years(ch))` would not work for me. I have just solved this by doing a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try *not* to use non-default origins with chron or at least convert them to default origins as soon as you can.

Here we create `ch0` which represents the same date times as `ch` but with default origin. The chron package does have the `origin` function (as well as the `origin<-` function) to help with this but it is not exported so we must preface it with `chron:::` .

```
ch0 <- chron(ch, origin = chron::origin(chron(0)))

# now we get the expected years
anios <- sapply(ch0, function(x){sprintf("%s", years(x))})
head(anios)
## [1] "2010" "2010" "2010" "2010" "2010" "2010"
```

Note:  An alternative to the expression for `ch0` above would be:

```
ch0 <- ch
chron:::origin(ch0) <- chron:::origin(chron(0))
```

Also the `sapply` could be replaced with:

```
format(years(ch0))
```

and without the sapply we don't even need `ch0` so this works:

```
format(years(ch))
```

**Update:** As of chron  ‘2.3.51’ (which was just uploaded to CRAN) `origin` is exported so the first line of code above no longer needs `chron:::`

```
ch0 <- chron(ch, origin = origin(chron(0)))
```

**Update 2:** Have updated Note.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I was not really sure how to "convert" a chron object to the default origin. This is helpful!!